# Roll dice - Javascript not working and image not uploading

Tags: javascript

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. But even the images are not loading anymore.

I have checked the code and I can't see where I am making the mistake. I am new to Javascript, so I am probably making some silly mistake.

```
let dice_1= Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;

let randomDice_1= "images/" + dice_1 + ".png";

let dice_2= Math.floor(Math.random()*6)+1;

let randomDice_2= "images/" + dice_2 + ".png";

let player_1= document.querySelectorAll("img")[0].setAttribute("src", randomDice_1);

let player_2= document.querySelectorAll("img")[1].setAttribute("src", randomDice_2);
```

[image: Refresh Me]

Comment: can you describe the tree of your main directory and where the js file is? can upload them some where for more detials?

Comment: Hi- my apologies.
I should have added more information included a screenshot of the folders and HTML strcuture.
I got the answer. I missed adding "images/dices" on the directory. I only had added "images".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This so dependable on your directory, fr example if js file is in a folder as a subdirectory and the images folder is in sibling with js folder, the address you have written is not correct:/
do you try this address :

```
"./images/" + dice_2 + ".png";
```

adding **./** at the beginning of the address

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I only needed the "image/dices".
Also I want to apologies. I think I should have taken a screenshot from the HTML structure.

Comment: @Always_asking23 there is no need to apologize, everybody can face this kind of problem